# How to bookmark a page which got parameters from one jsp page and generated output?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have one jsp which accepts avlue from textbox and passes it to another jsp page when button is clicked. Then by getting this value I have written one query which works perfectly.
Gives the output and generates the proper report.
But now i wants to bookmark this generated report. Can anyone tell me what i have to do for this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second page is invoked via a GET, then you simply have to use your browser to save the URL to your favourites - if it's invoked via a POST, then this isn't directly possible.

There are some workarounds, but using GET is the simplest option.

EDIT:
Also, if the operation is 'read-only' - i.e. it simply requests data and doesn't affect any long-term data storage values, the the HTTP spec reccomends using GET anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While you generate the asynchronous content, you should change the `hash`, the part of the url after the `#` mark. Then you can bookmark this page. On page load, check the hash, and load the proper content if it is necessary.